# Issue Related to Validated or Leave event of Textbox in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have written following code on Textbox Validated event :

```
 private void txtHbhakt1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

              //MessageBox.Show("Validated");
            txtHbhakt1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("abcd");
            txtHbhakt1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("abcd1");
            txtHbhakt1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("abcd2");
            txtHbhakt1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("abcd3");           

        }
```

i run the application and Hit TAB Key on Textbox.. it happens nothing.. why?
whenever i use autocompleteCustomSource on Validated or Leave event of Textbox TAB key doesn't working .. 
what is the solution?

Thanks..

Comment: As per this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource.aspx have you set AutoCompleteSource property to CustomSource?

Comment: Yes i have set AutoCompleteMode to Suggest and AutoCompleteSource to CustomSource

Comment: And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: TAB key doesn't working after addding AutoCompleteCustomSource.

Comment: Please remove the ASP.NET Tag because I think this is WinForms issue

Comment: This is strange, adding to the AutoComplete Source in either Validated/Validating/Leave event forces the focus back to the control. If you add a counter to the Enter event of the control it will increment 4 times for the 4 lines of Add, that means every line is forcing a Enter focus on the control...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tab key action seems to get conflicting orders when you are updating the custom source during the validation event.

A simple work around is to add the sources *after* the event has passed.  Using `BeginInvoke` seems to fix the problem:

```
void txtHbhakt1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txtHbhakt1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("abcd")));
  BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txtHbhakt1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("abcd1")));
  BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txtHbhakt1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("abcd2")));
  BeginInvoke(new Action(() => txtHbhakt1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add("abcd3")));
}
```